# Is there a way to create a constrained data type in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

As an example, a string that contains only a valid email address, as defined by some regex.

If a field of this type would be a part of a more complex data structure, or would be used as a function parameter, or used in any other context, the client code would be able to assume the field is a string containing a valid email address. Thus, no checks like "valid?" should be ever necessary, so approach of [domaintypes](https://github.com/friemen/domaintypes) would not work.

In Haskell this could be accomplished by a [smart constructor (section 1.2)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) and in Java by ensuring the type is immutable (all setters private) and by adding a check in the constructor that throws a RuntimeException if the string used to create the type doesn't contain a valid email address.

If this is impossible in plain Clojure, I would like to see an example implementation in some well known extensions of the language, like [Typed Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed).

Comment: Have you looked at [Prismatic Schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema)?

Comment: In Java your string is not guaranteed to be valid if you check it in constructor. You can have thousands of methods that will somehow change you string in your class. And you need to check every time, when you change it, that it is valid. Usually you just have a method 'checkString' that is called by convention in every method that changes the string. So I do not see actual difference between what you described and just a function that will create you data structure. You can cal it 'make-email' and use this every time you need to construct the email data structure.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious let's assume the constrained string is immutable (all setters private). Thus, if you want to change it, you cannot do it: instead of the original string you actually obtain the modified copy of it. To obtain the copy, its constructor has to be called, which contains the check. Thus I need to write the check only once - in the constructor. 

In Clojure I could bypass 'make-email' and just create invalid instance of the type directly. I want to prevent it, otherwise code operating on the type will have to make the checks by itself. In Java it is prevented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe, I understand now a question and I formulate in the comment my thoughts not really well. So I try to suggest an admissible solution to your question and then I try to explain some ideas I tried to tell in the comment.

1) There is a `gen-class` that generates compiled bytecode for a class and you can set constructor for the class there.

2) You can create a `record` with `defrecord` in some namespace that is private by convention in your project, then you
create another namespace with public api and define your factory function here. So the user of your public namespace will be able to call only public functions of your public namespace. (Of course, he can call also private ones, but with some another code)

3) You can just define a function like `make-email` that will return a `map`.
So you didn't specify your data structure anywhere.

4) You can just document your code where you will warn people to use the factory function for construction.

But! In Java if your code requires some interface, then it's user problem to give to your code the valid interface implementation. So if you write even a little bit general code in Java you already has lost the property of the valid email string. This stuff with interfaces is because Java is statically typed language.

Clojure is, in general, dynamically typed, so the user, in general, should be able to pass arbitrary data structure to arbitrary function without any type problems in compile time and it's his fault if he pass the wrong data. That makes, for example, this thing possible: You create a `record` and create a factory (constructor) function. And you expect a `record` to be passed in your code. But the user can pass a `map` with the same keys as your `record` fields names and the code will work.

So, in general, if you want the user of your code to be responsible for passing a required typed in dynamically typed language, then it cost nothing for user to be responsible for constructing it in a correct way that you provide to him.

Another solutions are: User just write tests. You can specify in your api functions `:pre` and `:post` conditions to check the structure. You can use typed clojure with the ideas I wrote above. And you can use some additional  declarative libraries, like that was mentioned in the first comment of @Thumbnail.

P.S. I'm not a clojure professional, so I could easily miss some better solutions.